# cannot grab post meta from extended Walker_Category class properly

Tags: metabox, walker

Trying to show some custom post meta inside an extended Walker_Category class.
I am very inexperienced with Object Oriented Design so this issue is quite difficult for me to solve

I am essentially trying to check the boxes of the categories that the user has already entered if they happen to edit a post with saved data

here is the code so far in the extended class:

```
    <?php
    class MyCategoryWalker extends Walker_Category{


    public $post_cb;


    //pass through the saved checkbox choices
    function __construct($custom_meta){
        $this->post_cb = $custom_meta;
    }


    //get the array of checkbox choices and convert it into a simple string format 
    function get_cat_rp_list(){

        $the_cat_list;
        foreach($this->post_cb as $cat_list){
            $the_cat_list .= $cat_list.', ';
        }
        $the_cat_list = rtrim($the_cat_list, ',');

        return $the_cat_list;

    }


    //actually builds the checkbox list
    public function start_el(&$output, $term, $depth, $args){

    echo self::get_cat_rp_list();

    $args = wp_parse_args(array(
      'name'    => 'my_category_input',
      'checked' => array(self::get_cat_rp_list()), //will input the string of checkboxes saved  

    ), $args);

    extract($args);

    $checked = checked(in_array($term->term_id, $checked));

    ob_start(); ?>   

    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" <?php print $checked; ?> id="category-<?php print $term->term_id; ?>" name="<?php print $name; ?>[]" value="<?php print $term->term_id; ?>" />
      <label for="category-<?php print $term->term_id; ?>">
        <?php print esc_attr($term->name); ?>
      </label>       

    <?php // closing LI is added inside end_el

    $output .= ob_get_clean();
  }
}
```

so that was in my class, For testing purposes I have added the "`echo self::get_cat_rp_list();`" in the `start_el()` method. On the particular post I have, there are only two categories stored in the post. However it echos out the two categories about 30 times (the same amount of total categories I have on this site actually)

here is my code to show the check list on the post:

```
$custom_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_custom-meta-box', true);

$newWalker = new MyCategoryWalker();

wp_list_categories(array(
  'walker'   => $newWalker,
  'name'     => 'my_category_input',       // name of the input
));
```

here is the code that saves/updates the checbox selection (which DOES work):

```
function save_pref_meta_box()
{
    global $post;
    // Get our form field
    if(isset( $_POST['my_category_input'] ))
    {
        $custom = $_POST['my_category_input'];
        $old_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_custom-meta-box', true);
        // Update post meta
        if(!empty($old_meta)){
            update_post_meta($post->ID, '_custom-meta-box', $custom);
        } else {
            add_post_meta($post->ID, '_custom-meta-box', $custom, true);
        }
    }
}
```